# Oracle ApEx Shuttle and Ajax On Demand Process

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to use a Shuttle item with an apex collection but when I attempt to add my P10_SHUTTLE value to my apex collection via an On Demand Process, while having selected 3 values from left to right, nothing seems to get ported across to the collection.

Also, after trying to return the value back from the collection to the P10_SHUTTLE item, again, nothing returns again.

Is there something different when it comes to using a shuttle item with an AJAX on demand process?

For your information, I am using Dene's method of returning the values: see: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:106:::NO

I am basically using all the same code that Dene's example does

I am not sure if it's to do with the following process of returning the values to the shuttle as all my select lists work but the shuttle item refuses to do so, i.e.:

```
if(l_El){
  if(l_El.tagName == 'INPUT'){
    l_El.value = l_Value;
  } else if(l_El.tagName == 'SPAN' && 
  l_El.className == 'grabber'){
  l_El.parentNode.innerHTML = l_Value;
  l_El.parentNode.id = l_ID;
}else{
  l_El.innerHTML = l_Value;
 }
}
```

With this code, do I need to do something different for Shuttle items, i.e. the tagName as I have also added == 'SELECT'

I'm stumped as to why I am having issues with Shuttles and Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt it is always worth using your browser's "View Source" option to see what Apex is doing under the covers.  In the case of a shuttle item, this is an Apex construct made up of two HTML select list controls.  If your shuttle item is called P10_SHUTTLE then the 2 select lists are called P10_SHUTTLE_LEFT and P10_SHUTTLE_RIGHT.

I just created a simple shuttle named P15_SHUTTLE on a test page and when I view the source I find:

```
<label for="P15_SHUTTLE" tabindex="999"><a class="t20OptionalLabelwithHelp" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp('13520996209337433800','287302151803630')" tabindex="999">Shuttle</a></label></td> 
<td  colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="13520996209337433800" /><fieldset id="P15_SHUTTLE" class="shuttle"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" class="shuttle" ><tr> 
<td class="shuttleSelect1"> 
<select multiple="multiple" id="P15_SHUTTLE_LEFT" size="10" class="shuttle_left"> 
<option value="Alpha">Alpha</option> 
<option value="Beta">Beta</option> 
<option value="Gamma">Gamma</option> 
</select></td> 
<td align="center" class="shuttleControl"> 
<a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_RESET"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_reload.png" alt="Reset"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_MOVE_ALL"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_last.png" alt="Move All"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_MOVE"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_right.png" alt="Move"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_REMOVE"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_left.png" alt="Remove"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_REMOVE_ALL"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_first.png" alt="Remove All"  /></a></td> 
<td class="shuttleSelect2"> 
<select multiple="multiple" id="P15_SHUTTLE_RIGHT" name="p_v01" size="10" class="shuttle_right"> 
</select></td> 
<td align="center" class="shuttleSort2"> 
<a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_TOP"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_top.png" alt="Top"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_UP"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_up.png" alt="Up"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_DOWN"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_down.png" alt="Down"  /></a><a  href="#" id="P15_SHUTTLE_BOTTOM"><img src="/i/htmldb/icons/shuttle_bottom.png" alt="Bottom"  /></a></td> 
</table></fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi @Tony Andrews, appreciate your response but based on your view source and simple example, which is all fine but are you able to add to your example, the means of selecting Alpha and Beta to the right, place these values into an apex collection and then retrieve these values back into the shuttle via an on-demand process. It is this area that I am having trouble with, the storing and retrieving of shuttle values. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do (I had a quick look at Denes's page but I'm not sure what it's all about!)

Comment: Tony, can you pls try the following: 1) create a shuttle item P10_SHUTTLE that is not based on a database column; 2) select 2 items from the let shuttle across to the right shuttle; 3) now try and store the values selected in the shuttle to an apex collection by using an ajax on demand process; 4) The problem I had here is that it only used the first item of my selection and not both selections (Alpha and Beta - only Alpha was saved; 5) Assuming you have just the one or two values stored, again with ajax, try and re-populate P10_SHUTTLE item described in point 1 above via an on demand process.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?  I don't have time to build a solution myself, but may be able to spot the flaw in yours.